# how to add margin in list view row?

Tags: android, android-listview, margin

i need to set the margin to top of the list view in xml.here is my xml code.
i try to add margin top to the relaytive layout it pushes down the whole list view but i want to push the first row of my list view down.

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu_left_Panel"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/gradiant"
      android:layout_gravity="start">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu_left"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/whiteCircle"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <ImageView
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_width="102dp"
      android:layout_height="102dp"
      android:padding="4dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Top padding to your listview in xml.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these attributes to your ListView.

```
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

The second one tells the ListView to use the padding to display the content when you start scrolling. So you've got the empty space only at the very top of the list.

Comment: ive tried padding but the problem is , the first row become a big clickabe icon and i dont want that effect.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot and update the xml ? Because what I said is the proper answer.